# Depth-First Search: order of the operators?

Tags: algorithm, search, depth-first-search

i have a question about DFS (but is valid also for BFS), i know how it works, we always expand the deepest node and we remove it from the LIFO queue. But suppose i have to start from a problem formulation, so i have some operators and an initial and a goal state.
My question is, i have to apply the operators in the same order for each node? For example if i apply the operators to the initial state following the order,

*Op1, Op2, Op3*

Now, for each children that i have expanded i have to apply the operators in the same order?

```
      IS
   1/ 2| \3
   /   |  \
  A    B   C
```

I mean, if i apply DFS here, i would expand the A node. Do i have to apply again Op1,Op2 and Op3 ?

I'm asking this because i'm an human and this is an exercise so i know which states and operators sequences lead to the solution but it does not, so i think i have to iterate using the same order trough all the search tree !

Comment: Can you explain the desired behavior by an example?

Comment: For example, we have as initial state <1,1,1> and we have to reach using DFS the goal state <1,2,3>. @MrSmith42

Comment: In terms of tree exploration, the order in which you apply the operators will only affect the order in which you visit the nodes, but generally you would do it always the same way, because why else wouldn't you (unless you have some heuristic formula that tells you which paths are more likely, but then you could use more advanced strategies like A*).

Comment: yes true but in this way we can get stuck easily.  I mean, maybe the goal  was in C applying Op3 (fig.) and since we applied as first Op1, we did not visited the C node but the A.